# How to find the user in specific SPGroup only for SharePoint:PeopleEditor control

Tags: server

I want to show a SharePoint:PeopleEditor in my layout page which user can select one user only on this control.

This is my peopleEditor setup:

```
<SharePoint:PeopleEditor ID="spPeoplePick" runat="server" CssClass="peoplePick" SelectionSet="User" MultiSelect="false" />
```

Now i also want to limit userName the peopleEditor can find that user can only find the user in a sharepoint group. For example, in the group member list below, if user input `Mary` in my peopleeditor control, he/she should get an 
 *No exact match was found* alert although **Mary** is one of the member of SPSite.

```
GroupA member List:
John
Harry
Dick
```

Is it possible to limit peopleEditor for a specific SPGroup?

Comment: Did you try with SharePointGroup property. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.peopleeditor.sharepointgroup

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, i haven't tested this but this should work:

```
<SharePoint:PeopleEditor ID="spPeoplePick" runat="server" CssClass="peoplePick" SelectionSet="User" MultiSelect="false" SharePointGroup="your group name" />
```